# show time in statustrip VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How to Show time in statustrip format (HH:MM:SS) that will automatically changed Like a 
(TaskBar Time in Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply add a ToolStripStatusLabel to your StatusStrip:

```
Dim WithEvents tm As New Timer With {.Interval = 1000, .Enabled = True}

Private Sub Tm_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tm.Tick
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End Sub
```